# Twitter share button not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, bootstrap-4

Currently working on freeCodeCamp's random code generator project. I'm getting strange behavior with my "Tweet" button. If the class is "twitter-share-button", the button will display properly, but won't populate the quote in the pop-up box, but if I change the class to "button", the button has no styling but the pop-up Tweet box populates correctly with the quote and author.

Please see code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="quoteBox" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
<h2>“What a curious power words have.”</h2>
<p>- Tadeusz Borowski</p>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p id="quote"></p>
    <h4 id="author"></h4>

  </div>
  <div id="twitter">
    <a class="twitter-share-button button" id="tweet-quote" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
  </div>​
</div>
<button id="getQuote" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg round btn-block">New Quote</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Loads quote on page load
  getQuote();


  $("#getQuote").click(getQuote);
});

function getQuote() {
$(document.body).css('background-color', 
colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?
 cat=famous",
 responseType: "json",
 success: function(response) {
  showQuote(response);
  $('#tweet-quote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?
  text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + response.quote + '" - ' + 
  response.author));
 },
 error: function() {
  alert('Error retrieving quote');
 },
 beforeSend: setHeader
});

function setHeader(xhr) {
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Key", 
 "pmTSpn6I45mshpuPkHokTQ01lAo1p1ugEH1jsnoOS19Gk3KQvB");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-
 urlencoded");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
}
}

function showQuote(response) {
 console.log(response);

 $('#quote').text(response.quote);
 $('#author').text(response.author);
}
```

I've spent hours on Twitter's dev page without any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the anchor tag with class "twitter-share-button" to trigger the `getQuote` function on click? Because currently I am not seeing that anchor tag wired up to do so. I *do* see the `button` element with id "getQuote" properly wired up in the `ready()` function tho.

Comment: The "getQuote" button ID is what should trigger `getQuote`, "twitter-share-button" should make the button look like a Twitter button and the ID "tweet-quote" should map to the JS so that when you click the Twitter button, the pop-up box is populated with the quote and author... if that makes sense.

That being said, I got it to work without the official Twitter button, but would like to get it working with the Twitter button.

Comment: Looks like its [this Twitter dev feature "intents"](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent)? Looks like the url is missing parameter names? E.g. `via` for the tweet author?